# Latitude/Longitude Dimension Reduction - 2D to 1D and back again

Tags: vector-spaces, cartography

I have a 2D array `(latitude, longitude)` which I would like to convert/map to a 1D integer (i.e. for machine learning regression purposes).

I would then like be able to convert back from the 1D integer to the latitude/longitude pair (i.e. at the ML testing phase). The conversion doesn't need to be exact, it could be some approximation.

As `-90 < lat < 90` and `-180 < long < 180`, and I had an idea of computing:

`(lat + 90) * (long + 180)`

in order to get some non-negative pseudo-unique integer, however, mapping back to the original `(latitude, longitude)` pair is problematic...

Is this possible or mathematically unfeasible?

Comment: You might consider just padding with enough zeros to capture the full precision, then concatenating the digits, if you don't need it to be symmetric between the inputs.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate? Im not sure I understand. Pad the array?

Comment: You have some numbers, presumably of the same length. Make them positive by adding 90 to lat and 180 to to long, as you suggest. Multiply by powers of 10 until they are all integers. Create the integer by taking a power of 10 times one of them and adding it to the other. E.g. if you have 38 and 125, then you could use something like 3800125. Then it's easy to extract what these came from: you just chop the integer in the right place. (And you know where that is.)

Comment: Interesting thanks, I wonder how this will work for ML regression purposes... ill give it a shot